# Advanced method swizzling in Objective-C, iOS 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, method-swizzling

The question is simple. I need the same as usually - how to replace the original method with my one but `@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)` in iOS9? It works in iOS9 simulator only, not real device.

Yes this code is called but then you get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

To test it I created a test app from "Master-Detail template" added a button and added the following code:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**UPDATED**

```
@implementation UINavigationController (Extension)

- (void)swizzledPresentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
{
    [ self swizzledPresentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:flag completion:completion ];
}

#pragma mark -

+ (void)swizzle:(Class)class oldSelector:(SEL)old newSelector:(SEL)new
{
    Method oldMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, old);
    Method newMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, new);


    if(class_addMethod(class, old, method_getImplementation(newMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(newMethod)))
    {
        class_replaceMethod(class, new, method_getImplementation(oldMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(oldMethod));
    }
    else
    {
        method_exchangeImplementations(oldMethod, newMethod);
    }
}

+ (void)load
{
    [self swizzle:UINavigationController.class oldSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:) newSelector:@selector(swizzledPresentViewController:animated:completion:)];
}

@end
```

And almost the same code is written on NSHipster website

**UPDATED**

**WARNING!** This bug is reproduced on very random devices (in my case it is iphone5 + ios9.0, but other users have newer devices and with iOS9.1).

Comment: Show us how you're doing the method swizzling.

Comment: Edited. I hope it will help to find a solution

Comment: How is your swizzled method not infinitely recursive?

Comment: ??? This part just means I call the original method.

Comment: @Avi: Google about "method swizzling". The method body of that method is switched with the "swizzled" method, so the code actually calls the original method.

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov hi did you end up fixing this? i am having the same issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is swizzling breaks checking `nil` values. Solutions for this case:

1)check if block is `nil` then replace it with empty non-nil block

2)use ready libraries. I tried: https://github.com/rabovik/RSSwizzle